# beam sdk run spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam

When I run apache beam sdk in spark cluster model.it throw `java.io.FileNotFoundException *** No such file or directory`.The program is simple wordcount. The environment information is as follows：

1. The spark version is 1.6.2
2. Apache Beam version is 0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
3. The parameter is as follows: 

   `bin/spark-submit
   --class org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount \
   --master yarn \
   --deploy-mode client \
   --supervise \
   --executor-memory 4G \
   --num-executors 4 \
   jar/word-count-beam-bundled-0.1.jar \
   --runner=SparkRunner --inputFile=pom.xml --output=result/res`

   when I run in Direct-Runner,The program run successed,And I can promise the file existed in the path.While run Spark-Runner it failed.
   Can anyone can help me find the issue? Thanks.